# Как сгладить цилиндр

Tags: blender

Всем привет, хотел бы узнать у знающих, как можно "сгладить" цилиндр знаю, что можно сделать больше сегментов, но хотелось бы более оптимизированный способ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для того чтобы сгладить грани цилиндра, следует использовать режим сглаживания "Smooth". Чтобы при этом основания цилиндра выглядело естественно, можно воспользоваться модификатором "EdgeSplit", который грани острые грани оставляет не сглаженными.[image: пример]